# How to find itertools product of tuples in a list of unknown length?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm working on a program in which I'm using `itertools.product()` to find combinations of  `n` number of tuples.
For example:

```
n = int(input())
```

Let's say the user inputs 3

```
a = [(True, False), (True, False), (False, True)]
```

Now I want to get the following as the output:

```
[(True, True, True),
 (True, True, False),
 (True, False, True),
 (True, False, False),
 (False, True, True),
 (False, True, False),
 (False, False, True),
 (False, False, False)]
```

I can do this when the number of tuples in the list is specified.

Comment: please add a running example

Comment: You just need to unpack: `list(itertools.product(*a))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product works the following:

```
>>> list(itertools.product([True, False], [True, False]))
[(True, True), (True, False), (False, True), (False, False)]
>>> list(itertools.product([True, False], [True, False], [True, False]))
[(True, True, True),
 (True, True, False),
 (True, False, True),
 (True, False, False),
 (False, True, True),
 (False, True, False),
 (False, False, True),
 (False, False, False)]
```

So what you need to do is

```
import itertools

n = int(input())
a = [(True, False) for i in range(n)]
list(itertools.product(*a))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a single iterable that you want to repeat, you can use the `repeat` argument of `itertools.product`

```
import itertools

n = int(input())
a = (True, False)
list(itertools.product(a, repeat=n))
```